# How to make list elements instances of an object

Tags: python, list, class, variables, element

I am trying to iterate through a list of string and make each element an instance of an object.
I made a simplified version just to demonstrate my issue. When I run this code, I get an error saying that 'David' is not defined. I understand what I have done wrong: when I wrote 'People[i] = Person()', People[i] became the variable name instead of calling each element from the list.

How do I call each element on a list and make it a variable, so that in this case, when I print(David.name), it would print 'David'?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Unassigned"



People = ["David", "Emma", "Brian"]

for i in range(len(People)):
    People[i] = Person()
 
print(David.name)
```

Comment: I've tried using placeholders like { }.format() or '%s' % but did not work

Comment: don't try to dynamically create variables like this, it is the *wrong way to do this*. Instead, use a *container*. A list works. If you want to map strings to a person, use a `dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tweak for the above snippet you can try,

```py
class Person:
    # init constructor
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

People = ["David", "Emma", "Brian"]

# instead of creating dynamic variable use a dict
peoples = {}

for p in People:
    # init object with person name
    peoples[p] = Person(p)
 
# access based on person name
print(peoples['David'].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to dynamically create variables, which is not a good idea.  The way you *can* do it is like so:

```py
people = ["David", "Emma", "Brian"]

code = "class {name}:\n    pass\n{name}.name = '{name}'"
for name in people:
    exec(code.format(name = name), globals())

print(David.name)
#prints:
#'David'
```

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT assign variable names like that or mess with globals. Use dictionaries instead:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Unassigned'

People = ["David", "Emma", "Brian"]

#create a list of your objects
obj_list = [Person() for i in range(len(People))]
#convert People names to dictionary keys
dictionary = dict(zip(People, obj_list))

print(dictionary['David'].name)
#Unassigned
```